# can't find/retrieve results from a specific table with datamapper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml, datamapper

I am working on a sinatra app with datamapper connected to a mysql database and am having problems retrieving/finding records from only one specific table. I can insert into it with datamapper find but when I try to do @sleepEntries = Sleep_Log.all I get the following error: ArgumentError: argument out of range. When I load everything into irb I get the same error. I also turned on the ability to see the queries and I get back SELECT `id`, `start_time`, `length`, `timestamp` FROM `sleep_logs` ORDER BY `id` when I call Sleep_Log.all. When I connect to the mysql database through the mysql command line tool I can confirm that there are entries in that table. When I run the query that datamapper is erroring out on I have no problem getting the results. Here is my datamapper model info for Sleep_Log

```
class Sleep_Log
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :start_time, Time, :required => true
  property :length, Integer, :required => true
  property :timestamp, DateTime, :writer => :private

  belongs_to :user
end
```

This is what the table looks like in the database accessed through describe sleep_logs;
[image]

What is weird is that retrieve results from all other tables.

The backtrace from irb
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a full backtrace?

Answer (score 0):

If you try `Sleep_Log.first`, do you get the error?  If so, could you paste in the record, or one which also shows the error?

How was the table constructed?  Are you using DM to inspect already entered records?  Or are you entering them through DM too?

Comment: I still get the error if I use first. All of the table entries were inserted through DM but the table itself was created with the mysql command line utility. I have other one to many relationships with other tables that work and I created and am doing the same thing. The only way that I have found to get the results is to talk to the database directly. @sleepEntries = repository(:default).adapter.select('SELECT * FROM sleep_logs')

Answer (score 0):

We just encountered the exact same problem. In our case it turned out that you have to use DateTime. Mysql doesn't have a Time database type and saves as DateTime. However, DataMapper doesn't get it and blows up. If you switch your model to use DateTime DM will get it.

Comment: This is exactly the problem I was having, and changing the model to DateTime fixed it. But actually MySQL does have a time object, so is this a bug in DataMapper?